# is there a way to load data from oracle to LDAP database?

Tags: database, oracle, ldap, etl, openldap

I am looking for a way if there a way to load data from oracle to LDAP database ? the end goal is to generate test data by taking the sample of 10 records available in the LDAP database currently.

Comment: Do we talk about users? Can you provide some example data from Oracle?

Comment: Please be more specific. When you say "oracle", do you mean you have user data stored in a custom table in Oracle database? (as compared to Oracle Internet Directory, or one of its many other LDAP-compatible products) And this is going FROM oracle TO OpenLDAP? Also, is this a one-time load, or recurring?

Comment: Oracle has a `dbms_ldap` package that lets you interact with an LDAP server from PL/SQL.  You can certainly write some code to read and/or write data from one to the other.  Whether that makes the most sense will depend on specifics about your use case and how familiar you are with the LDAP APIs.